# Area of the shaded region using integral calculus.

Tags: definite-integrals, area, centroid

Please everyone...what is the area of the shaded region from the image and how to calculate it using integral calculus?

Also if possible can you guys help me with the centroid of that region?

[Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhJpB.jpg)

Comment: For the area, why use calculus? Why not just elementary geometry? But if you insist on using calculus, can you at least set up an integral?

Comment: For the centroid, use a) symmetry, b) the standard result for the centroid of a circular sector, and c) take moments about the $x$-axis

Answer (score 2):

it is the area of the square minus $1/4$ of the area of the circle:
$$36-\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot6^2$$